# How to reserve memory for std::vectors within an std::array?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stl, containers

I have a `std::array` with a fixed number (`numLines = 4`) of `std::vector`; each `std::vector` will contains dynamic numbers of elements, which I know the max size of each `std::vector` (`numMaxSteps = 32)`.

Thus:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, numLines> mSequences;
```

Since I'm processing audio at higher rate, its mandatory for me to **NEVER** allocate memory during the process (hence, it introduces clicks and glitches).

But I'm not sure how to `reserve` memory of each `std::vector` on init.

Is there a way? Or I need to iterate each item of `std::array` and do`.reserve(numMaxSteps)`?

Note that I need to keep `.size()` at 0: only `.capacity()` need to grow up.

Comment: Are you okay with paying for zero initialization of the vector?  Do you know what the size of the vector will be at compile time?

Comment: Why do you use vector when you know the max size? Why not `std::array<std::array...`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes, it will be always init later. And as I said, I only know the "max size" of each vector at compile time. At run time it will range from 0 to 32 (but at that point, the memory should already be allocated).

Comment: @bartop: because `std::array` and `.size()` will always be max size, not the "dynamic" size during the time.

Comment: @markzzz Worst case scenario - write thin wrapper for `std::array` that defines `size` the way you need. And it would reusable I guess

Comment: I'm guessing your real question is *"how to avoid writing a special initialization function that I then must remember to call once?"*

Comment: After your definition of `mSequences`, a simple loop `for (auto &m : mSequences) {m.reserve(numMaxSteps);}` will do it.   I'd be a little uncomfortable if your processing code is resizing, even if you have reserved space - since, depending on how new sizes are calculated or on how resizing is done - the new size may exceed capacity, in which case, a reallication may happen anyway.

Comment: @Peter if "the new size may exceed capacity", the reallocation will be the last of my problems ;)

Comment: @markzzz - fair enoough.  Just that the way you're doing it (reserving, and then having any form of data processing doing the actual resizing) strikes me as error prone.

Comment: @Peter: why? I'm processin a patterns of (max 32) notes that will vary once loop (with different notes, so 16, 20, 28, 8), and so on.

Comment: @markzzz - in your application, that may be fine.  I was thinking more generally, in terms of setting size to zero and then resizing to a size calculated later - such approaches often introduce problems due to forgetting to resize in some edge case, or making some other error resizing (e.g. code resizes to one X,  some other code - like a loop assumes a size Y which is greater than X, and falls off the end).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a thin wrapper, if you don't mind writing a few more letters when accesing the vector:

```
struct vect32 {
    vect32() : vect(32) {}
    vector<int> vect;
};

array<vect32, 10> sequences;

sequences[0].vect.push_back(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating from your comment on Marshall's answer:

> I only need a "fancy" way to reserve memory on init

It doesn't get any fancier than an IILE:

```
auto mSequences = []{
  std::array<std::vector<int>, nunLines> ret;
  for (auto& v : ret)
    v.reserve(maxCapacity);
  return ret;
}();
```

The lambda will be called automatically when it's time to initialize mSequences, and thanks to the wonders of NRVO will initialize it directly.

It can even be used to initialize complex objects declared `const`.

And if the idea of an IILE violates your coding standards, you can always make a named free function out of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way? Or I need to iterate each item of `std::array` and do `.reserve(numMaxSteps)`?

That's the way ;-)

But I agree with @bartop; with your needs, you should consider `array<array<int, 32>>` instead.

Comment: Uhm? If `mSequences[1]` contains an "array" of 12 items instead of 32, it will iterate 32 elements, not 12, because `.size()` will always be 32.

Comment: If you need variable number of elements for each "line", and you don't want to store them elsewhere, then yes, array of arrays will not work for you. But it sounded like you already had a list of lengths elsewhere - possibly I misunderstood.

Comment: Not at all. Its a dynamic list that will vary "up to" 32 elements.

Comment: Then an array of vectors, each one resized, is the way to go.

Comment: Which is my code :) I only need a "fancy" way to reserve memory on init hehe

Answer (score 0):

What you describe here seems a perfect case for [boost.static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html).

This container allows you to pre-allocate compile-time size, but after that it supports `push()`/`pop()`/`insert()`/`remove()` etc and it's `size` function and iterators respect real run-time defined size.